# Third TabBarView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cOpx.png)

Is that possible to create the third tabbarview as in the picture?

Answer (score 0):

yes, possible. you also can make your own tab bar view.
you can use `PageView` as the page and `Row of Item` as the Tab to make it.